# Pinescript: How to implement a machine learning trading strategy thats completed in python to pinescript

Tags: python, machine-learning, tradingview-api

So I want to trade altcoins using BTC as a leading indicator, especially to the downside. I have built a DQN trading model in python and it works but it lags since I am not that well read on how to get less / minimal latency from fetching the data to when my model has reached a prediction.

I want to use tradingview directly but it doesnt have an API for me to use, how should I go forward in building a ML tradingbot using as good data as Tradingview has (supports most crypto exchanges and has data down to the seconds interval). Are there other platforms that support API or that you can use python to build an indicator / model on ?